# Hide some of the fields of user profile of profile2 module

Tags: users, organic-groups

I am using Drupal 7 [profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module for creating user profile and [Organic group](http://drupal.org/project/og) module for group managemnet.

I have **user status** field in user profile, and there are two options(radio button) for visibility of profile field like **1.** Visible in Group **2.** Invisible.

**Visible in Group** is selected then any group member can see the **user status**

**Invisible** then no one can see the **user status** field

Now I want to know that is there any way to unset the profile field during viewing. Is any hook calling during user view event ?

I have also the code that checks whether user being viewed and logged in user are member of same group or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_entity_view` can be used all core and most contrib entities and the more specific `hook_user_view` can be used when the user account is used - this is, however, not the same as the user profile itself.

You should note that this wont effect fields and entities displayed by views.

Comment: @googletrop: I want to unset some of the profile fields: i mean I want solution like **unset($profile['fieldname'])** is it possible to achieve it

Comment: @mohit_rocks Yes

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this way it is not working. I mean field is still displayed

Comment: @mohit_rocks Did you inspect the variables to see where the field markup is located - you are aware that it's not the field itself but the field content you need to disable. You can also use manage display if you always want to hide the field

Comment: @googletrop: I don't want to hide the field all the time, actually it depends on the value of radio buttons.